# How to show a text inside a <TabHost> tag? Android

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-widget, android-layout, textview

Hey, I have a tab host, and I wanted that when I clicked on a tab shows a text. I've declared the text on the corresponding xml file that the class calls.

here is the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=" "
    >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And I write a message like this on the class:

```
txtView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtView);        
txtView.setText("This is rated calls");
```

But it doesn't show anything. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because your FrameLayout height is set to fill_parent so its filling up the screen pushing your textview out of the window.

The way around it is to set the height to 0dip and then give it a layout_weight="1" but don't give any weight attribute to the textview or tabwidget.